# View Model Locator - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, clase, uwp

es que estoy queriendo crear el VMLocator dentro de un proyecto que estoy haciendo, pero no encuentro la manera.

Tengo esta documentacion:

https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/21/xamarin-forms-with-mvvm-light/

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37354/viewmodellocator-reference-in-xaml

pero no hallo la forma de hacerlo, no se si es el xamarin, ya lo habia hecho una vez en UWP pero no he podido con Xamarin:

```
public class VMLocator
{
    public VMLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MiClaseVM>();

        App.VMLocator = this;
    }

    public void Register<VM, V>() where VM : class
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<VM>();
    }

    public MiClaseVM MiClaseVM => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MiClaseVM>();
}
```

No se que Nugget tengo que descargar para que me funcione